# Declarative mechanism for Django model rows

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

With some frequency, I end up with models who contents are approximately constant. For example, I might have a set of plans that users can sign up for, with various attributes -- ID, name, order in the list of plans, cost, whether the purchaser needs to be a student/FOSS project/etc.. I'm going to rarely add/remove/change rows, and when I do there's likely going to be code changes too (eg, to change landing pages), so I'd like the *contents* of the model (not just the schema) to be managed in the code rather than through the Django admin (and consequently use pull requests to manage them, make sure test deploys are in sync, etc.). I'd also like it to be in the database, though, so I can select them using any column of the model, filter for things like "show me any project owned by a paid account", etc..

What are good ways of handling this?

I think my ideal would be something like "have a list of model instances in my code, and either Django's ORM magically pretends they're actually in the database, or makemigrations makes data migrations for me", but I don't *think* that exists?

The two workable approaches that come to mind are to either write data migrations by hand or use regular classes (or dicts) and write whatever getters and filters I actually want by hand.

Data migrations give me all the Django ORM functionality I might want, but any time I change a row I need to write a migration by hand, and figuring out the actual state involves either looking in the Django admin or looking through all the data migrations to figure out their combined impact. (Oh, and if somebody accidentally deletes the objects in the database (most like on a test install...) or a migration is screwy recovering will be a mess.)

Just using non-ORM classes in the source is a clearer, more declarative approach, but I need to replacements for many things I might normally do in the ORM (.objects.get(...), __plan__is_student, .values(plan__is_student).annotate(...), etc.).

Which of these approaches is better presumably depends on how much ORM functionality I actually want and how often I expect to be changing things.

Are there other good approaches for this? Am I missing some Django feature (or add-on) that makes this easier?

Comment: I have now asked this on the django-users mailing list (https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/7ffUkQGzRAc/m/zU3-bmAVBQAJ) as well.

Comment: I think I have encountered something similar. This kind of data can usually be considered like configuration. I want to put this configuration data into the deployment pipeline, not into migration files, since not all deployments necessarily have the same configuration. The data would be declaratively described in code (i.e. it would be in version control but it doesn't necessarily have to be Python) and there would be some machinery that would do anything needed to reach the desired state in the database regardless of the starting state. I haven't found any existing solutions to this yet.